# Progress Bar in DLL

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating DLL which contains loop of some data

how can i display progress bar

I tried to create new windows Form and displayed the same in for loop

but it ask me to close the form every time

Comment: Ideally, don't. Have your DLL exposes progress *events* and let the main application, which knows how it's UI works, what technology it's using, etc, decide how best to surface this information. DLLs that say "I know best about how to show the UI" tend to be *far* less reusable.

Answer (score 2):

People on SO are not here to write code for you - they are here to solve problems. Anyway, I am going to show you how you could do it, and then you can write your code based on what I provide.

First of all, a "DLL" is a Dynamic-link library. Therefore, you can attach it to any project you have (winform or unity 3d game and no, you will not do it but let's just say it could be used in both cases) so if you are already writing DLL's, make it usable in a lot of scenarios and provide the programmer with a lot possibilities for manipulation.

So, your task is divided in 2 parts here:

- Calculate data
- Inform the user of what stage of the calculation they are at now

For this task, we will use events and a simple `for` loop to show you how it works.

First of all, let's create an `EventArgs` class that will store all the data we want to pass when the programmer from the other code catches the event:

```
public class CustomEventArgs
{
    public int OldResult { get; set; }
    public int NewResult { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when we have an event class let's implement it in our code.

```
public class YourDllCalculation
{
    // In the .NET Framework class library, events are based on the EventHandler delegate and the EventArgs base class.
    // So we create delegate using our newly created class to represents it like EventHandler
    public delegate void ResultChangeEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);

    // Now we create our event
    public event IzborRobeEventHandler ResultChanged;

    // Local storing variable
    private int Result = 0;

    // This is method from which you inform event something changed and user listening to event catch EventArgs passed (in our case our CustomEventArgs)
    protected virtual void OnResultChange(CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        ResultChangeEventHandler h = ResultChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, e);
    }


    // We will use this method from new code to start calculation;
    public void StartCalculation()
    {
        // Calculation will be done in separate thread so your code could proceed further if needed
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Calculate);
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void Calculate()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            OnResultChange(new CustomEventArgs() { OldResult = i, NewResult = i + 1 });
            Result = i;
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Pause thread from running for 1 sec
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have our code we can use it like this in our Winform:

```
// Add at top
using YourDllNamespace;


public YourForm()
{
    // Creating our class for calculation
    YourDllCalculation calc = new YourDllCalculation();
    calc += CalculationResultChanged;
    calc.Calculate();
}

private void CalculationResultChanged(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
{
    // Here do whatever you want with passed values
    // e.OldResult;
    // e.NewResult;
    // it will fire each second
}
```